# How to change precedence of constructor in haskell

Tags: haskell

I was doing an exercise on implementing bracketing for objects in my `Maybe` data type:
What I wanted to achieve was this kind of bracketing:

```
-- MyJust 'a'

-- MyJust (MyJust 'a')

-- MyJust MyNothing

data MyMaybe a = MyNothing | MyJust a

instance Show a => Show (MyMaybe a) where
  showsPrec _ MyNothing = showString "MyNothing"

  showsPrec p (MyJust x) =
    showParen(p>6)(showString "MyJust ".showsPrec 7 x)
```

My code works, but there are some things I don't understand. First what is the precedence of `MyJust` operator (it must be less then 6 ,or I would get something like `(MyJust (MyJust 'a'))`? And the other question is how can I change it to 9 for example, so that I get `(MyJust (MyJust 'a'))`? I tried `infixl 9 'MyJust'` but it doesn't work. I am asking this to better understand precedences in haskell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're confusing the actual precedence of Haskell operators with the precedence-tracking scheme used by `showsPrec` to ensure that the printable representation uses parentheses in the correct manner to match the actual precedence.

In Haskell, "application" of one term to another, whether it's function application like `sqrt 16` or constructor application like `Just 4` is always effectively left associative with a fixed precedence of 10 (i.e., larger than any infix operator precedence), and this cannot be changed.

In order to write a `Show` instance that correctly reflects this precedence for a constructor, you want to write:

```
instance Show a => Show (MyMaybe a) where
  showsPrec _ MyNothing = showString "MyNothing"
  showsPrec d (MyJust x) = showParen (d > app_prec) $
    showString "MyJust " . showsPrec (app_prec+1) x
    where app_prec = 10
```

Note that this follows the template for `Leaf` given in the [documentation for the `Show` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Show).

If you change the value of `app_prec` to something else, then things will appear to work fine if you're only showing the `MyMaybe` type or nested `MyMaybe` types, but will start to break down if you combine it with other types.  For example, using my definition with `app_prec = 10`, the following works correctly:

```
> MyJust (Just 10)
MyJust (Just 10)
```

But if you change it to the incorrect `app_prec = 6` to match the definition in your question, it produces broken output:

```
> MyJust (Just 10)
MyJust Just 10
```

Comment: And why when I write `showsPrec d (MyJust x) = showParen (d > 0) $ ... where app_prec = 10`  the call `MyJust (Just 10)` doesn't return `(MyJust (Just 10))`? Because the d is always greater then 0 even for the first `MyJust`.

Comment: The `d` argument represents the precedence *context* in which the current expression is being displayed, not the precedence of the expression itself.  The initial precedence context is 0.  It's actually set by the `shows` function whose definition is `shows = showsPrec 0`.